# Optimisation Theory-basic idea

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

X is compact set.
X has two different points. Prove that X has at least two extremal points?

Anyone can help me on this?
I have no clue for where to start. Thank you!

Comment: It is one possible interpretation that you are looking for points realizing the diameter of $X$? Consider $d:X×X\to\Bbb R_+$ and its maxima.

Answer (score 1):

There're a lack of information in the question : When talking about optimization, there should be a cost function. I suggest to give a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

In that case, the image of $f$ should be a compact in $\mathbb{R}$ so is bounded. $f(X)$ is bounded imply it has minimum and maximum values, which are at least two extremal points as expected.

Comment: @LutzL, thank you, I edited